# How to find near polygons

Tags: qgis, proximity

I have some polygons with attributes (in my case, some polygons have health establishments) and others without attributes (without health establishments). Is there a function that I can use in order to attribute health establishments to the polygons without it (using a distance approach)?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

I think you can using the following steps:

---

1. Split your polygon layer to two:

   - One polygon layer with health establishments
   - One polygon layer without health establishments

---

2. Then make sure you have the **refFunctions** plugin installed and enabled by going to the menubar:

   ```
   Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
   ```

---

3. Highlight your polygon layer without health establishments, access the **Field Calculator** and enter the following expression (*replace with the **layer name** of the layer with health establishments and the **field** of which you want to copy the attributes from*):

   ```
   geomnearest('layer_name_with_health_establishments', 'Field_Name')
   ```

   [image: Field Calculator]

   Your layer now should contain the nearest health establishment.

---

4. (Optional). You can then join or merge the two polygon layers into one using tools such as from the menubar:

   ```
   Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge Shapefiles to One
   ```

   or from the Processing Toolbox:

   ```
   QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector general tools > Join attributes table
   ```